# Avoiding/Working Around ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] in Python (3.5) MySQL.Connector

Tags: python, mysql, database, sockets

I have written a script that suggests users for other users based on data stored about them in a MySQL database. Currently I am simply doing nested for loops to iterate over two result sets that both contain each user and all of their relevant data and compare the values stored in each field relevant to the suggestions for each pair of users via our algorithm. This script is currently run in the cron tab every minute and usually takes about five to ten minutes to complete. This is because we want the most up-to-date suggestions as possible. Currently, an error keeps getting thrown when the script is run in this way (runs perfectly fine in isolation) that halts the script. Here is the stacktrace for this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-     packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 226, in      recv_plain
     chunk = self.sock.recv(4 - packet_len)
 ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Is there any way to avoid this and still run the script in this way? I feel like with the transactional nature of databases this should be no problem, even if multiple calls to the script are running (I am aware that there are some issues with memory running out if no cap is put on the amount of calls being made). If there is not such a way to do this, what are the conditions that must be met to prevent this error? As I understand so far, this error often occurs when a connection to the database is closed on the server side before the client is finished requesting data from that connection. How would one avoid this if so? Currently I making connections to the database in several methods that get called multiple times throughout the script that create and destroy connections to the database like so:

```
def queryfunct(sql, args):
  cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='mypassword', host='localhost', database='mydb')
  try:
    cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)
    cursor.execute(sql, args)
    #moar things
    ...
  finally:
    cnx.close()
```

Thank you in advance for your much-appreciated time.